# AG Grid: can replace header icon with Material Icon, but not with Font Awesome Icon. How to?

Tags: icons, font-awesome, ag-grid

I am able to "selectively replace grid column header icons" **successfully** in AG Grid with Material Icons when using the following css:

```
.ag-theme-mysite .ag-icon-expanded {
    --ag-icon-font-family: "Material Icons";
    --ag-icon-font-code-expanded: "\e166";
}
```

But attempting the same with Font Awesome 6 Free is **unsuccessful**:

```
.ag-theme-mysite .ag-icon-contracted {
    --ag-icon-font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --ag-icon-font-code-contracted: "\f061";
}
```

Can someone tell me what needs to be edited, in order for Font Awesome's icons to be a selective replacement for some of our AG Grid's header icons?

We are attempting to use the proper code for Font Awesome (and none work, in any case):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FWIW,

It was an issue with some free icons not being included in what we believed was the free icon set (Classic-Solid). Also, should you be looking how to get the icon to be Solid instead of Regular, you need to add the proper weight to the CSS:

```
.ag-theme-mysite .ag-icon-contracted {
    --ag-icon-font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --ag-icon-font-code-contracted: "\f152";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```